# How do I define the signature of a function that must be implemented by instances of a class?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Say I have a class `Book`:

```
public class Book{
   public string Title {get; set;}
}
```

I want every book to have a `Read` function that returns a string and accepts a page number - but the internals will be different for every book (poor example, I know).  How do I define the signature of a function that must be implemented by instances of this class?

Something like this:

```
public class Book{ // need to make this abstract?
   public string Title {get; set;}
   public abstract string Read(int pageNum);
}

// I want to define instances that define their own behavior...
public static Book It => new Book(){ // can't create instance of abstract...
   Title = "It", 
   Read... // what do I do here?
}
```

My main concerns are:

- Keeping things as simple as possible.  Implementing interfaces under abstract classes works, but it gives me n*2 things to worry about as I add more instances.
- I will need to add a large number of these custom functions - passing Funcs through constructors seems unwieldy.
- In practice - this is used to define a `Tenant`.  The `Tenants` are defined in-memory, and have many static properties like `domain`, `name`, `adminEmail`, etc.  Those are tenant-specific properties... but now I am trying to implement tenant-specific *behaviors* - like `GetBooks` or `FilterUsers`.  I would like to keep implementation as simple as humanly possible.  Right now I have "If TenantA, do this, else if tenantB, do this..." sprinkled throughout my code.  I'm trying to consolidate all tenant-specific logic and detail in one place - on instances of the `Tenant` class.
- Further examples of Tenant specific behavior - you have a SaaS forum software.  On the homepage of Forum A, you `GetCoverPhoto` by reading from a static file.  On the homepage of Forum B, you `GetCoverPhoto` by reading from a blog homepage.  Currently, I say "If Forum A, do this, else If Forum B, do this".  This is the type of tenant-specific behavior that I want to define on the Tenant object, instead of in code.  I don't want any tenant-specific code in my core logic.

Is there a simple feature/pattern in the C# language that will achieve this?

Comment: @AlexD I've tried that - I'll update my question with where I'm struggling.

Comment: Ah, OK, `abstract` does not apply here then. You may consider making `Read` a delegate.

Comment: "passing Funcs through constructors seems unwieldy" Really? `Read = pageNumber => LoadPage(pageNumber)` is unwieldy? It says exactly what you need to say: for this instance of `Book`, you load a page by calling the LoadPage method. The way to specify different read behavior for each Book instance is to *specify different read behavior for each Book instance.*

Comment: @JoeWhite - no need to be sarcastic.  There's nothing wrong with my observation that a constructor with 20 items in it is undesirable.  Not to mention n*2 lines per every function in the class declaration (one per func, and then one per usage).  Even the answer author agrees.

Comment: The scenario is still unclear. You have to better explain why different instances of a tenant would do 20 things, but all that things differently from any other tenant

Comment: @NineBerry - Added a bullet with an example.

Comment: The question remains: do some of the tenants share the same behaviour or do you have to program the behaviour differently for each one?

Comment: @NineBerry - the shared behavior in in my service layer.  I'm only trying to define tenant-specific behavior on the tenants.

Comment: You are not answering the question. If there are really 20 things that every tenant does differently than any other tenant, go and kick management into the balls.

Comment: @NineBerry - I've tried my best. Why is it so hard to believe that there might be a core platform with some shared "core" behavior, with tenants implementing some number of custom extensions?

Comment: Still not sure about the reqs if I got them right but have some detailed answer in my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What NineBerry said is very valid.

There is one other way of accomplishing what you might want. If you want to dynamicly inject the read method implementation into a Book. This can be seen as [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). And can be done as interfaces like in many languages, but in simplest form in C# it can be done by delegates. Example:

```
public class Book{
   Func<int, string> readFunc;
   public Book(Func<int, string> readFunc)
   {
     this.readFunc = readFunc;
   }
   public string Title {get; set;}
   public string Read(int pageNum) { return readFunc(pageNum); }
}
```

Then use it as:

```
public static Book It => new Book(){
   Title = "It", 
   Read = (pageNum) => ... // Do actual reading in delegate
}
```

EDIT: With more detail on requirements (but still not everything is obvious) I would do something like this:

```
public class Tenant 
{
  // core things go here
  public Extensions Extensions { get; }
}

public class Extensions : IEnumerable<IExtension>
{
  private IList<IExtension> list = new List<IExtension();
  private Tenant { get; set; }

  public Extensions(Tenant tenant)
  {
    Tenant = tenant;
  }

  public void Add(IExtension extension)
  {
    extension.Tenant = Tenant;
    list.Add(extension);
  }
}

public interface IExtension
{
  Tenant { get; set; }
  // shared interface of extensions if any can be abstracted
}

public interface ICoverPhotoExtension : IExtension
{
  Photo GetCoverPhoto();
}

public class FileCoverPhotoExtension : ICoverPhotoExtension 
{
  public Tenant { get; set; }
  Photo GetCoverPhoto() { } // gets photo from file
}

public class BlogCoverPhotoExtension : ICoverPhotoExtension 
{
  public Tenant { get; set; }
  Photo GetCoverPhoto() { } // gets photo from blog
}
```

usage:

```
Tenant tenant; // initialized somehow
var coverPhotoExtension = tenant.Extensions.FirstOrDefault<ICoverPhotoExtension>();
Photo photo = coverPhotoExtension?.GetCoverPhoto();
```

Comment: Thanks for this - though it seems a bit "dirty" - what if I have 20 different functions that need to be declared?

Comment: This is definitely not intended usage.

Comment: This is really cool and likely the direction I'll go - thank you!

Comment: Is there some way I can email you to ask for (paid) help with more details?

Comment: Your comment made me think and "come of of the closet". Just google me and contact on first link.

Comment: Nice!  I just see linkedin inmail though (I don't have premium).... do you want to update your SO profile with email?

Comment: Nope please contact me via linkedin.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Interface IBook{ 
   string Title {get; set;}
   func<int,string> ReadPage
}
```

Use containment over inheritance.  In the interface example above there is a function in every book that implements IBook that will return a string for that page.

```
public class MyBook : IBook{

   public Title : {get;set;} = "MyBook";
   public func<int,string> ReadPage =(pagenumber)=>{
       return GetText(pagenumber);
   }  
   public string GetText(int pageNumber){
      //read the page text by number here.
   }
}
```

I would make GetText an extension method similar to this, so each book doesn't need to implement GetText itself.

```
public static class XBook{
    public static string GetText(this IBook book, int pageNumber){
        ///do the work here and returng string
    } 
}
```

To use the Extension method concept:

```
using XBook;
public class MyBook : IBook{

   public Title : {get;set;} = "MyBook";
   public func<int,string> ReadPage =(pagenumber)=>{
       return this.GetText(pagenumber);
   }  
}
```

There are more ways to do this... for now, give it a try.

Comment: I commented on NineBerry's answer with my concerns - this might be better but can you demonstrate its usage?

Comment: Updated post for you

Answer (score -1):

Having different instances of a class implement functions differently is not possible. Instead, you inherit a new class where you implement the separate behaviour.

```
public abstract class Book
{
   public string Title {get; set;}
   public abstract string Read(int pageNum);
}

public class ITBook : Book
{
   public override string Read(int pageNum)
   {
      // Code here
   }
}
```

Then use the class like this:

```
public static Book It => new ITBook()
{ 
   Title = "It", 
}
```

You could use a property of a delegate type in the Book class to use different functions in different instances of the Book class, but these functions would not have access to the other properties and methods of the instance they would be used by.

Comment: "You could use a property of a delegate type in the Book class to use different functions in different instances of the Book class, but these functions would not have access to the other properties and methods of the instance they would be used by."

This is not true. If the delegate was a closure, but it would need to be constructed after constructing the Book object.

Comment: I'm trying to keep the code footprint as small as possible... if I have 10 different books - that's 10 different interfaces and static classes = n*2 things to worry about.  Is there a simple method that allows me to achieve this with n things to worry about?

Comment: If you need to implement retrieving pages differently in code for every single book, there is something else very wrong in your design. If you tell us some more about the actual background of the question, it would be easier to help.

Comment: @NineBerry I've updated my question with some more context - thank you.